# Metadata in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, reflection, metadata, decorator

I'm trying to wrap my head around Decorators & Metadata in Typescript and thought angular would be a good project to look for some kind of best practise.

In the old versions (e.g. 2.1) they are using DecoratorFactories and inside they apply metadta over the `reflect-metadata` API proposal( https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.x/modules/%40angular/core/src/util/decorators.ts)

In the new versions they started implementing their own system for the decorators(https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/util/decorators.ts) and just appended the data to the constructor where it is easy accessible. Like:

```
@SomeDecorator(someDataObject)
class SomeClass { ..... }

console.log(SomeClass['__annotations__'])
console.log(SomeClass['__paramaters__'])
console.log(SomeClass['__prop__metadata__'])
```

Someone has any idea why they are doing this? Advantages? Disadvantages?

Comment: Don't do what they're doing. It's overly complicated and it is based on a use case where they use an incompatible non-standard decorator implementation to ahead of time compile apps that are no longer written in TypeScript or JavaScript. In fact, their source code is an absolute nightmare of bad practice that you should avoid like the plague.

Comment: TBH, I have no idea why Google makes core of Angular 4+ so complicated again.